# How can I use the "using" directive in a .ascx?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm bored, on writing C# code on .ascx, to use this syntax :

```
<%    
     foreach (OriginalPackage.MyPack in OriginalPackage.MyPacks) {
     }
%>
```

instead of

```
     foreach (MyPack in MyPacks) {
     }
```

writing the right `using OriginalPackage;`

So, is there a way to use the `using` on the .ascx?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the [`@import`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb44kack.aspx) directive instead:

```
<%@ Import namespace="OriginalPackage" %>
```

> Explicitly imports a namespace into an ASP.NET application file (such as a Web page, a user control, a master page, or a Global.asax file), making all classes and interfaces of the imported namespace available to the file. The imported namespace can be part of the .NET Framework class library or a user-defined namespace.

Comment: but required memory/time to import this? I mean, if in page.ascx I use `<%@ Import namespace="OriginalPackage" %>` and on .ascx.cs also `using OriginalPackage;` it's a waste of resource? Or it doesnt matter?

Answer (score 6):

I haven't written an ascx file myself, but [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s42bzt8x(v=vs.100).aspx) suggests you want:

```
<%@ Import namespace="OriginalPackage" %>
```